# Reading Weight From Weighing Machine in Web pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

Currently i am working on a project where my requirement to read data from Weighing machine through com port and showing that data in Textbox in Asp.net Web application.please help

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You will need to deal with buffers, timing, parsing, threading. Not all the weighting indicators provide the same output so you will need a guide to your weighting indicator unit and set it up to either handshake mode or continuous data mode. I would say that continuous mode is a bit easier to handle.

You can check http://sourceforge.net/projects/netwico/ - you will see it is not a simple matter of few lines of code.